# Does the following numeric assignment result in an implicit cast in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, casting

This question is mainly out of curiosity since I couldn't find anything in the official C# documentation and the performance cost is probably completely negligible.

Basically, I'm wondering if there is any runtime cost difference between:

```
float i = 0;
```

and

```
float i = 0.0f;
```

I would assume that the compiler is smart enough to convert `0` into `0.0f` at compile time and directly assign it without a cast. Is this assumption correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference, see decompiled through [csharp labs](https://sharplab.io) IL code:

C# code:

```
using System;
// Run mode:
//   value.Inspect()      — often better than Console.WriteLine
//   Inspect.Heap(object) — structure of an object in memory (heap)
//   Inspect.Stack(value) — structure of a stack value
public static class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        float i = 0;
        float i2 = 0.0f;

    }
}
```

IL code:

```
.class private auto ansi '<Module>'
{
} // end of class <Module>

.class public auto ansi abstract sealed beforefieldinit Program
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig static 
        void Main () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 14 (0xe)
        .maxstack 1
        .locals init (
            [0] float32,
            [1] float32
        )

        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: ldc.r4 0.0
        IL_0006: stloc.0
        IL_0007: ldc.r4 0.0
        IL_000c: stloc.1
        IL_000d: ret
    } // end of method Program::Main

} // end of class Program
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code example there is nothing different between the two.  You have declared the type as a `float` so regardless of having the f at the end or not it's going to be a float.  The f just gets ignored.

The f comes into play when performing equations or assigning generic variables such as using the `var` keyword.

For example:

`var value = 0; // this is assigned as integer.`

`var value = 0.0f // this is assigned as float.`

`var value = 0.0; // this is assigned as double.`

And here's a calculation example:

**Note:**  *To understand floating points in it's entirety is a completely different lesson but knowing that calculations are performed differently based on type such as integer, float (f), double (d), or decimal (m) is mostly what matters*.

Notice how the math is different from type to type.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(1 / 3);
        Console.WriteLine(1f / 3);
        Console.WriteLine(1d / 3);
        Console.WriteLine(1m / 3);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    // OUTPUT
    // 0
    // 0.3333333
    // 0.333333333333333
    // 0.3333333333333333333333333333
}
```

Also note that when you set a type in a calculation ONLY that portion of the calculation gets that type result.  Consider this example of mixed types in calculations:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //float + integer
        Console.WriteLine(1f / 3 + 1 / 3);

        //double + integer
        Console.WriteLine(1d / 3 + 1 / 3);

        //double + float
        Console.WriteLine(1d / 3 + 1 / 3f);

        //decimal + integer
        Console.WriteLine(1m / 3 + 1 / 3);

        //decimal + decimal
        Console.WriteLine(1m / 3 + 1 / 3m);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    // OUTPUT
    // 0.3333333
    // 0.333333333333333
    // 0.666666676600774
    // 0.3333333333333333333333333333
    // 0.6666666666666666666666666666
}
```

---

**Updated to include information based on comment below**

To update my answer based on the comment below and compilation vs runtime generation of objects.

All known types are generated at compile time.  So in your question, yes the compiler will assign 0 to float since it's known.

All generic types have metadata that's generated at compile time; so the compiler can answer questions against the types and flag errors.  However, the type itself isn't generated until runtime; and if that type is a value type or reference type changes how it's generated. Consider this signature:

`public void MyMethod<T>(T myType)`

Since this method is generic, a new one is created for each different value type, at runtime, only when that type is used, and only once per value type (the same value types reuse the same generated type).  Take a look at the code below.

```
MyMethod(12);           // new type method built at runtime taking integer
MyMethod(12d);          // new type method built at runtime taking double
MyMethod(12);           // ** resuses already built type method taking integer
MyMethod(new Person()); // new type method built at runtime taking Person
MyMethod(new object()); // ** resuses type method built taking Person but uses object pointer.
```

So you can see that the compiler can help us resolve type conflicts but the type that uses the generic types doesn't exist until runtime; and it's important to know when they exist and how they are used between value and reference types.

Finally we have `dynamic`.  This never gets resolved at compile time and is in fact ignored until runtime.  You can do whatever you want here; it's a bit like writing JavaScript; that little rebellious devil.  Consider this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    dynamic value = 1;
    Console.WriteLine(value);

    int integer = value;
    Console.WriteLine(integer);

    value = "Hello World";
    Console.WriteLine(value);

    string text = value;
    Console.WriteLine(text);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
// OUTPUT
// 1
// 1
// Hello World
// Hello World
```

Notice that here I not only take an unknown type but I assign it to a known type... I then change that type altogether to another type and then assign it to another type.  The compiler doesn't care and it all works... The problem is if I modify it so that things don't match then I get a runtime exception instead of compile time.  Depending on how you use dynamic this can be a big problem.

Hope this all helps clarify things a bit.  Remember; known types (compile time), generics (compile time metadata, runtime types), and dynamic (runtime).

Comment: I realize they are logically the same. I was more wondering if the compiler performed the implicit cast at runtime or at compile time. Based on answer posted by Access Denied, seems like the compiled IL code is the same.

Comment: @Zeenobit  I've updated the answer at the bottom with more information that I believe you'll find useful.  I'm not trying to get you to change the answered question so don't worry about that.  I just want to help you understand how to determine this automatically in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
  float i = 0; // 'conversion' can be done at compile-time
```

Formally, there is an implicit conversion from `int` to `float`. But when the `int` in question is a compile-time constant, like in this case a literal `0`, the conversion is done by the C# compiler.

So both of your lines give the same program (same IL).

However, in this case:

```
static void M1(int n)
{
  float i = n; // actual conversion at run-time
  Console.WriteLine(i);
}

static void M2(float f)
{
  float i = f; // same types
  Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

there could be a diference, because `M1` needs to convert from `int` (`Int32`) to `float` (`Single`), whereas `M2` needs no conversion.